# How to set rules in windows firewall to allow a gRPC service in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: asp.net-core, grpc, windows-firewall

I have a gRPC that is hosted in a ASP.NET Core application.

When I try to connect from another computer, I get a timeout error, but if I disabled the firewall in the server computer, it can connect.

I have tried to open the port that is used by gRPC for all protocols, and it doesn't work.

I have tried to allow a program, the .exe file of the ASP.NET Core application, but it doesn't work.

I have tried to allow svchost.exe, and it doesn't work.

I would like to allow the process instead to open the port, but if the only it is to open the port, it is ok.

Thanks.

Comment: [Please check this doc.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-firewall/create-inbound-rules-to-support-rpc)

Comment: @JasonPan Thanks for the link. I have follow the guide to create the 2 rules: To create a rule to allow inbound network traffic to the RPC Endpoint Mapper service and "To create a rule to allow inbound network traffic to RPC-enabled network services" but it doesn't work. It is true that in the beggining it tells it is needed an inbound rule for TCP 135 and a rule for outbount (sent). But In the steps to create the rules both are inbounds rules. So I am not sure how to configure.